# Attempted import error: 'Navigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-dom

pls help me to deal with this error Attempted import error: 'Navigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom' my react-router-dom version is 4.1.1 pls don't tell me how update to 5v or v6 because  in that verisons i am facing many errors so pls tell how to fix this error in 4.1.1 verison of react-router-dom the error is Attempted import error: 'Navigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'. you all can also see the img of the error [image: error img]

## my code here

```
import {  Navigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAppSelector } from "../app/hooks";

export function PrivateRoute({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const location = useLocation();
  return isAuthenticated ? (
    children
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Redirect instead of Navigate in version 4, like so

```
import {  Redirect, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAppSelector } from "../app/hooks";

export function PrivateRoute({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
const { isAuthenticated } = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth);
const location = useLocation();
    return isAuthenticated ? (
       children
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />
    );
  }
```

Comment: see my edited code and tell what to copy paste i dont understand

Comment: I have modified your snippet, with using Redirect

Comment: the error gone by using the command npm install --save react-router-dom@4.2.2 but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing Navigate with Link.

```
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
...
<Link to "/login" state={{ from: location }} />
```

Comment: facing this problem Attempted import error: 'Routes' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Answer (score 0):

Recent update to answer:

> In version 6 of React Router, the **Redirect** component is replaced with **Navigate.**

So your code should work now.